# Autowired on ReactiveCrudRepository, generic base service with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I am developing a generic service where I need to declare that the repository is autowired. But the ReactiveCrudRepository receives the @NoRepositoryBean annotation.

Current code:

```java
@Service
public abstract class BaseService<T extends Model, ID extends Serializable>
        implements CrudService<T, ID> {

    private ReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID> repository;
```

Error:

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'ReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID>' type found.
```

Comment: I don't think Spring is able to aurowire such generic objects.

Comment: You need define an interface of your own that implements ReactiveCrudRepository and specifies the <T, ID> types. See https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data